# Объединение выводов

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, python-2.x, вывод

Господа, подскажите, пожалуйста:

1. как можно ограничить один из циклов, количеством результатов выполнения второго (конкретно, цикл 2 количеством результатов цикла 1)?
2. как объединить результаты выполнения нескольких циклов в 1 строке?

Цикл 1 - генерирует дату и время:

```
date_fmt = '%b %d %H:%M:%S'
start_range = '0'
end_range = '121'
start_date = DT.datetime.strptime('Jan 15 06:30:00', date_fmt)
last_date = DT.datetime.strptime('Jan 15 06:55:00', date_fmt)
while start_date <= last_date:
    step = DT.timedelta(seconds=random.randrange(int(start_range), int(end_range)))
    print(start_date.strftime(date_fmt))
    start_date += step
```

Результат:

```
Jan 15 06:30:00
Jan 15 06:32:38
Jan 15 06:33:11
...
```

Цикл 2:

```
i = 1
n = i
while i <= 6:
    print(i)
    print(n+i-1)
    i += 1
```

Результат:

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
...
6
6
```

И 3 часть:

```
t = 'your id'
print (t)
```

Результат:

```
your id
```

В моем видении, конечный вывод должен быть таким:

```
Jan 15 06:30:00 your id 1
Jan 15 06:30:00 your id 1
Jan 15 06:32:38 your id 2
Jan 15 06:32:38 your id 2
Jan 15 06:33:11 your id 3
Jan 15 06:33:11 your id 3
...
Jan 15 **:**:** your id n
Jan 15 **:**:** your id n
```

Все задублированное так и задумано.
Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно, что бы каждая пара последовательных значений datetime была связана с одним и тем же id-ом циклически, то так:

```
from pprint import pprint
from itertools import tee
from random import randrange
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def ts_range(ts_beg, ts_fin, rng_beg, rng_fin):
    i = 0
    while ts_beg <= ts_fin:
        yield i, ts_beg
        i += 1
        ts_beg += timedelta(seconds=randrange(rng_beg, rng_fin))

date_fmt = '%b %d %H:%M:%S'
start_date, last_date = [datetime.strptime(d, date_fmt)
                            for d in ['Jan 15 06:30:00', 'Jan 15 06:55:00']]
start_range, end_range = 0, 121
t = ' your id '
f = lambda i: str(1 + i // 2 % 6)
for it in tee(ts_range(start_date, last_date, start_range, end_range)):
    g = (ts.strftime(date_fmt) + t + f(i) for i, ts in it)
    pprint(list(g))
    f = lambda i: str(1 + i // 2)
```

**Вывод:**

```
['Jan 15 06:30:00 your id 1',
 'Jan 15 06:31:38 your id 1',
 'Jan 15 06:32:21 your id 2',
 'Jan 15 06:33:27 your id 2',
 'Jan 15 06:35:13 your id 3',
 'Jan 15 06:35:56 your id 3',
...
 'Jan 15 06:49:36 your id 5',
 'Jan 15 06:49:51 your id 5',
 'Jan 15 06:50:11 your id 6',
 'Jan 15 06:51:52 your id 6',
 'Jan 15 06:53:09 your id 1',
 'Jan 15 06:53:16 your id 1',
 'Jan 15 06:54:55 your id 2']
['Jan 15 06:30:00 your id 1',
 'Jan 15 06:30:42 your id 1',
 'Jan 15 06:31:03 your id 2',
 'Jan 15 06:32:13 your id 2',
...
 'Jan 15 06:52:24 your id 13',
 'Jan 15 06:53:17 your id 13',
 'Jan 15 06:54:06 your id 14']
```

А для попарно последовательного возрастания id-ов нужно убрать деление по модулю на 6.
[Демо](https://rextester.com/IFLO17677).